# Visual Studio Code - launch.json - start javaw instead of java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am currently trying out the lanterna project in java and have to call my jar not with java.exe but instead with javaw.exe.

My launch.json in Visual Studio Code looks like that, but I do not know how to switch it just in this project to javaw:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    
    {
        "name": "Launch Java Program",
        "type": "java",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "javaw.exe",
        "console": "externalTerminal",
        "mainClass": "",
        "externalConsole": true,                //user input dosen't work if set it to false :(
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "preLaunchTask": "build",                 // Runs the task created above before running this configuration
        //"jdkPath": "${env:JAVA_HOME}/bin",        // You need to set JAVA_HOME enviroment variable
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "startupClass": "${workspaceRoot}${file}",
        "sourcePath": ["${workspaceRoot}"],   // Indicates where your source (.java) files are
        "classpath": ["${workspaceRoot}"],    // Indicates the location of your .class files
        "options": [],                             // Additional options to pass to the java executable
        "args": []                                // Command line arguments to pass to the startup class
    }

],
"compounds": []
```

}

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: no, just having a separated console opened

Answer (score 0):

In your launch.json, inside of one of your configurations add this line (Well change it to point to your jdk of course):

```json
"javaExec": "C:\\Users\\_____\\.jdks\\corretto-19.0.2\\bin\\javaw.exe"
```

So your launch.json could look like this:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "${file}",
            "javaExec": "C:\\Users\\_____\\.jdks\\corretto-19.0.2\\bin\\javaw.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

The only problem I've got with this is that console.log() and any errors don't show up in console like they're supposed to. Still looking for a solution to that.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it next time I will work with my lego robot ;)